# Can't use result of linecache.getline() in if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

In python, I'm working on doing some work with linecache.getline() to help with reading from a config file (a .txt file).
Here is my code:

```
animation = linecache.getline("config.txt", 2)
print (animation)
if animation == "True":
    animation = True
elif animation == "False":
    animation = False
else:
    config_error(2)
```

Note: Ignore config_error(2), it's just a function I've made to say something's gone wrong.

My problem is that I'm always being brought to the else statement. As you can see, I've even printed out animation to only find that it print's True. Anyone got any advice or knows what's going wrong?

Comment: I suspect that your `animation` has a trailing newline or other whitespace. Print `repr(animation)` instead of just animation to see if there's anything funny there. If it's whitespace, store `linecache.getline(...).strip()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andras said, the problem is linecache.getline() is including a trailing newline, so your comparisons to "True" and "False" never match.

Use linecache.getline().strip() and it should work.

Comment: OK. Thank's a lot! But can I ask what a trailing newline is? Just want to know my enemy and how to kill it.

Comment: Each line of config.txt is a bunch of "normal" text characters - letters, numbers, spaces and so on - followed by an "end of line" or "newline" character - essentially what you get when you press the Enter key on the keyboard. The linecache.getline() function returns the normal text AND the newline at the end.

Comment: The [strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) function is a bultin method for python's strings that removes spaces and newlines from the start and end of a string.

Comment: Thanks @Tom McDermott